# How can I get my directive to cancel drag action on the dragleave event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, event-handling

In order to facilitate manually sorting of some nested ngRepeats, I've implemented 3 directives: draggable, droppable, and drop boundary.

Draggable and droppable work just fine, using event listeners to enable and control drag and drop operations on `<div>` elements within my inner ngRepeat.  However, I want to restrict this functionality to only allow drag and drop within a given ngRepeat (i.e. users shouldn't be able to drag from one result set to another).

My Angularjs view, including the ngRepeats, look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="tank in tankdata">
   <div dgs-drop-boundary>
      <div class="row bin" dgs-droppable drop="handleDrop" bin="bin" id="bin-{{$index}}" ng-repeat="blend in tank.TankResult.BlendFills">
           <div class="row item"  dgs-draggable item="{{ blend }}"  id="item-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}" >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to happen is have my drop boundary directive prevent a draggable item from leaving the outer `<div>`.

I've created an event listener for 'dragleave' on the drop boundary directive:

```
el.addEventListener(
                    'dragleave',
                    function (e) {
                         //What goes in here?
                    },
                    false
               );
```

However, I can't figure out how to approach cancelling the drag.  I tried triggering 'dragend', but I can't get that to work:

```
        el.addEventListener(
            'dragleave',
            function (e) {
                var event = new Event('dragend', {
                    'view': window,
                    'bubbles': true,
                    'cancelable': true
                });
                document.dispatchEvent(event);
                return false;
            },
            false
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  el.addEventListener(
        'dragleave',
        function (e) {
            var event = new Event('dragend', {
                'view': window,
                'bubbles': true,
                'cancelable': true
            });
            document.dispatchEvent(event);
            return false;
        },
        false
    );
```

add line of code e.preventDefault(true);

Comment: Does not work.  I had tried that, and I can still drag the element outside of the container and into the next ngRepeat.